# Regarding javascript document.forms[]

Tags: javascript

If I have a piece of javascript code in my jsp (as shown below):

If `var frmObj=document.forms['cseeForm'];`

and I did not create a form named cseeForm in that jsp, does the above code means: create a new form called cseeForm? and assign it to frmObj?

Please help, I am maintaining a web application, but I could not find any form object named cseeForm in that jsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.forms` simply returns a collection of the forms that currently exist.   So, if you haven't created a form with that name, then

```
var frmObj = document.forms['cseeForm'];
```

will simply assign `undefined` to `frmObj`; no new form will be created.

For more information, check out the [relevant MDN page on document.forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.forms)